# Draw a non intersecting polygon after detecting corners with OpenCV

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, corner-detection, python

I have this image:

[image]

and I am using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` to detect the coroners, so now I have this:

[image]

The corners are in red and the numbers show the order of which `goodFeaturesToTrack` got the corners.. for example, corner with number 0 is the first detected one, etc...

If I were to connect the dots based on that order, I would get a messy polygon so I thought of using a function that given a random set of points, it returns them in an order with which the polygon wouldn't intersect..

I found [this function](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52627/120607) and it does exactly what I want.

However, although the polygon doesn't intersect, for this example I am not getting the same shape as the initial one (I am getting a non self-intersecting polygon but a different shape).

Does anyone have an idea to fix this? I was thinking of making `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` return an ordered set of points but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you could start with a delauny triangulation and afterwards remove all edges which separate the polygon, without isolating vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the polygon, you can threshold the image and extract the outer contour with `findContours`, using `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` as the mode to obtain the outer contour and `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` as the method. `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points (see the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)).

If you want to use corner detection results and arrange them in correct order to make the polygon, you'll have to trace the boundary of the shape and add those corner points into a list as you find them along the boundary. For this, I think you can use `findContours` with `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` and `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` to get every pixel. Still, you might not find your detected corner points exactly on the contour returned from `findContours`, so you'll have to use a proximity threshold.